# Delete a specific data table's rows

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable

I've filled a dictionary with  parents as keys  and their children as value's `List<>`  from a `DataTable` relations  that works really good, and every  children is saved as a structure called  `Definition` and inserted in a `List<Definition>`

```
 structure Definition
  {
     int id; 
     int atom; 
     int id_d
  };
```

but what i want to achieve is while iterating over the the value's list on the `Dictionary<Definitions,List<Definitions>>`, I mean, the children of the `DataRelation`, i'd want to delete certain rows in a `DataTable` true tables that values are being taken from iterating the `List<Definitions>` value's `Dictionary`
i.e

```
Dictionary<Definitions,List<Definitions>> dataRelation;
DataTable parents;
DataTabale children; 

 foreach(var it in dataRelation)
 {
     for(int i =0 ; i< it.value.count : i++)
     {
          if(is the row i want to delete)
          {
               Children.delete(with the structure's Definition value parameters )
          }

     }
 }
```

the  structure's `Definitions` variables  are the same as  The `DataTabale` colum's name.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that i not really know what the issue is, but i'd use this readable approach:

```
var rowsToDelete = from cRow in children.AsEnumerable()
                   join  r in dataRelation.Values
                   on new { 
                      id   = cRow.Field<int>("id"), 
                      atom = cRow.Field<int>("atom"), 
                      id_d = cRow.Field<int>("id_d") 
                   } equals new { r.id, r.atom, r.id_d }
                   select cRow;
foreach(DataRow rowToDelete in rowsToDelete)
    rowToDelete.Delete();

// now use a dataadapter to actually delete this row from the datasource
```

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding the title, I recently changed it, sorry!

Comment: @SalvadorRomo: no problem, but it doesn't change the meaning of your question so the answer should still work